# Remote File Access

Tags: remote-access

I'm looking for a feasible solution for remote file access. I want to be able to access my files stored on my HomeServer using any web browser. Also, if possible I want to be able to mount the drives too (however i'm sure the best way is through a VPN).

I've looked at OwnCloud, however I gather that it wouldn't support this type of setup. I'm also looking into using OwnCloud instead of Dropbox; with 2TB of files, I wouldn't want that data to be synced on each machine!! :D

I found this, this would be perfect if it was able to run on a linux machine: [thingy](http://www.nbdev.co.uk/projects/hap.aspx)

I'm running Ubuntu Server, with the files accessible at `/StoragePool/`

**how is this off-topic? There hasn't been a single feasible solution posted, so I don't see a `debate` being fired up.**

Comment: A NAS would have (maybe) been a better solution. I have one and it allows remote file access, even via a web browser.

Comment: @alex probably, but I wanted to build my own server. I have a 4670k and 9TB worth of drives for £600, (with the drives costing £250) so it was a much better choice. 
OwnCloud works great, so I recon I made the best decision after all. Thanks for the input.

Comment: `"Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. ` This is why it was closed and will remain closed.

Comment: While this is geared toward software recommendations I would recommend [reading this post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/47225).  It'll help you be able to ask questions like this, in a better way.

Comment: @KronoS and that's why most people I know hate stacksocial!

Comment: @StevenChorkley not quite sure what you mean by that...

Comment: @KronoS You guys are just totally unfair, so they use other sites :)

Comment: I don't see how we're being so unfair.  There are a set of rules in order to ask or answer questions here.  We try to uphold the highest of quality while still allowing new content.  If something doesn't meet the quality requirements we give it a chance to be edited and improved.  I've given you an answer as to why this is closed.  I've given you a tool to follow in order to increase the quality of the question.  What more do you want/need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally managed a great solution! I decided to setup ownCloud as a hidden directory but then dawned upon this idea.

So, for this solution I used [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org). I moved my main directory `/StoragePool/` into `/StoragePool/files/` and created `/StoragePool/ownCloud/`. I then installed ownCloud into the newly created directory, setup an account, then deleted `/StoragePool/ownCloud/data/%UserName%/files`. All I had to do then was create a symbolic link to `/StoragePool/files/`. If you wished, you could do that for any / all users.

It's not a perfect solution, however my files are backed up. I am now able to access all my files from a web interface, and along with select sync and a desktop client can also use it as a Dropbox replacement.

I hope this helps someone else out there!